# what does SMB/CIFS mean in ubuntu gnome

Tags: gnome

every time I start my machine so many processes appear and at last of their name and job a small bracket is seen in which ever sentence ends with `ok` but seconds before the desktop appears a statement like `starting SMB/CIFS active directory server` appears and it ends with fail showing that that process failed

my question is what does those abbrevations `SMB/CIFS` mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIFS = Common Internet File System
SMB = Server Message Block

You use CIFS if you want to mount a Windows network share.
You use SMB if you want to share printers etc. with Windows computers.

How to use CIFS and SMB in details is big task to answer so you will have to go hunting your self.

You have probably the Samba client or server installed.

Comment: Actually, you are always using SMB for both purposes. CIFS is a dialect of SMB. [According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `The Server Message Block (SMB) Protocol is a network file sharing protocol, and as implemented in Microsoft Windows is known as Microsoft SMB Protocol. The set of message packets that defines a particular version of the protocol is called a dialect. The Common Internet File System (CIFS) Protocol is a dialect of SMB. [...]`

Answer (score 0):

SMB and CIFS are the same thing, a network system for files to pass over a network like an Intranet. Just google it. Still, nothing to be worried about.